# MySQL Select: Case When Or Something Else?

Tags: mysql

First time poster, long-time reader. I have been teaching myself code othe past 6-8 months and I like to think that I am fairly getting decent at the PHP/Javascript/MySQL stack. I definitely love the community that Stack has built because it really helps to share problems with people who understand things a little better.

So my question is probably relatively simple, but I am not sure how to use Case When...Then here. (Or whether that is even correct to use!). Basically what I want to say in my where clause is: if this column = 1, then also process this condition. Something like:

```
SELECT product_name
FROM b2c_products, b2c_sellers
WHERE b2c_products.productId = b2c_sellers.product_Id AND CASE WHEN b2c_products.productType = 1 THEN b2c_sellers.seller_country = '$country' END;
```

I hope that gets the idea across - I know this is a simple problem, I just am so new to SQL! Thanks a LOT in advance.

Comment: It sounds like `CASE` is unnecessary, and you really want something like `b2c_products.productType = 1 AND b2c_sellers.seller_country = '$country'`, or maybe something like `b2c_products.productType != 1 OR b2c_sellers.seller_country = '$country'`.  Can you give more guidance on what conditions you want to apply?

Comment: Hey @EdCottrell, thanks for the reply. Basically, I want to add that condition to the Where clause in the event that the productType = 1. Most of the time the productType will not be 1, and in those cases, I would not want to set the condition that 'b2c_sellers.seller_country = '$country''. Does that make a bit more sense? Thanks!

Comment: How are you joining the two tables? You don't have a `JOIN` clause of any sort.

Comment: It's still not clear what you are trying to do. I *think* you want all products where the `productType` is not 1 or where the `productType` *is* 1 and the `seller_country` also matches your variable. If so, `CASE` is the wrong approach, and something like my second example in my comment above is correct. But as @staticsan points out, you don't have a `JOIN`, so the relationship between these tables is unclear.

Comment: Sorry about that! I had just written it out instead of copying from my actual code. Fixed. Anyways, so what I am trying to do is grab all the products - as long as the column `b2c_products.productType` is not equal to 1. If it DOES equal 1, I want to further add the condition that this product being pulled back should have a seller whose country `b2c_sellers.seller_country = '$country'`. Sorry for the confusion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Case statements work don't work in the way you're trying, they mainly for selectors, see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case.html or staticsan's answer. You can use them in WHERE clauses, but generally it should be considered for data transformation.

MySQL does have the concept of IF statements: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if which can be nested. For example

```
1 = IF(b2c_products.productType = 1, IF(b2c_sellers.seller_country = '$country', 1, 0), 0)
```

As an alternative, you can achieve what you're after with nested with simple AND clauses which will allow you to use indexes too, e.g.

```
SELECT product_name
FROM b2c_products, b2c_sellers
WHERE ((b2c_products.productType = 1 AND b2c_sellers.seller_country = '$country')
   OR b2c_products.productType <> 1);
```

As a side note, make sure you escape '$country' to avoid SQL injection.

Comment: Thank you so much - that worked perfectly. I had no idea that you could nest And clauses like that. As far as SQL injection goes, I am using PDO prepared statements - should that be good enough or should I be doing something else? Thanks a lot!

Comment: assuming you're using PDO statements with :country notation (http://www.php.net/pdo.prepared-statements) and not using the RAW SQL in the ticket, then you're good.

Comment: Just for completeness, MySQL's `IF()` functions are merely another way to write a `CASE` clause. Some programmers (myself included) find `CASE` easier to read than `IF()`. You can nest `CASE` clauses, too.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, no, what you're trying to do is far from obvious.

`CASE` is normally used in the fields of a `SELECT` statement (between `SELECT` and `FROM`) to alter the returning data. A simple example might be:

```
SELECT userid, CASE WHEN disabled = 1 THEN 'Disabled' ELSE '' END AS disabled FROM users;
```

The way I think of how `CASE` works is that it runs on every row of output.

Comment: Ah I see. That was actually my thinking too after reading the documentation - something to basically alter the end results. Bittersweet in that what I was thinking was right but still uncertain as to how to proceed!